# Verilog clock generator error?

Tags: verilog

I write simple code using ISE 14.7 to generate clock signal, but the output in iSim is always 1, until I change = with <= then the clock works, could you tell me why?

```
module nonblocking( clk );
 output reg clk;

 initial 
   #10 clk =0;

 always @ (clk)
#10 clk = ~ clk; // change to <= to work

endmodule
```

Comment: Is this code for synthesis or simulation? What toolchain/simulator/synth tool/compiler are you using? What exactly are you trying to achieve given that you don't have any delay before flipping the value of `clk` and are using `always @ clk`?

Comment: I'd prefer simply as: `initial clk = 0; always #10 clk = ~clk;`

Answer (score 0):

This code honestly doesn't make any sense.

Your current code states that based on `clk`, the value of `clk` should be `~clk`.
When you use `<=` you are at least specifying a nonblocking assignment, which makes slightly more sense, but still doesn't.

If you want a clock generator for simulation, use the following within an initial block (giving a 10ns period):

```
forever begin
    #5 clk <= ~clk;
end
```

If you want a clock generator for FPGA synthesis, either connect a physical oscillator to your device's clock input pin, or use a built-in oscillator (if available on your device). You can always use a DCM/PLL/CMT/MMCM/whatever your FPGA calls it to adjust the clock frequency.

Comment: the forever needs to be inside the initial.

Comment: I use ISE 14.7 , and as i told you just when i use nonblocking assignment, the clock appear in iSim

Comment: @HayderAl-Amily Although it may work, it's not a clear way of doing it. If you want to generate a clock, generate it in a way that would be clear to other readers of your code. The fact that it's in a non-edge-triggered process assigning to a register over time makes it not appear similarly to how clock generators are typically made for testbenches, and this code is not consistent with what one would need to write to be synthesizable.